# Could AWS EMR run multi spark application in parallel in single cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I know an EMR cluster could have multiple steps and EMR will run these steps sequentially. But is it possible to let EMR run steps in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-work-with-steps.html):

> You can also choose to run multiple steps in **parallel** to improve cluster utilization and save cost.